# Metal Oxide Semiconductor (MOS) Capacitor strong inversion

Tags: capacitance, semiconductor-physics

Why the electron bands in the Body of the MOS capacitor do not bend much futher after the threshold voltage is applied? What stops them from doing it? For reference Modern Semiconductor Devices for IC from Hu chapter 5 is used.

Comment: Well, what does chapter 5 say, and why do you not agree?

Comment: Its not that I do not agree. Its just that its pretty unclear and basically the effect is just mentioned but not explained at all. I just cannot explain to myself why after Vthreshold, the bands do not bend much futher. What stops it from doing it ?

Comment: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Chenming-Hu_ch5.pdf

Comment: Section 5.5 explains it, although you need to have understood at least 5.2 and how the induced surface charge behaves.